# post_class printing literally

Tags: php, wordpress

When using this code, it actually prints < ? php post_class();?> but does print the custom taxonomy. I'm confused as to what I'm missing here

```html
<!--FAQ-->


 <div class="main-faq-div">

    <div class="faq-box">
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'faq', 'posts_per_page' => 40 , 'paged' => 1,);
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      $counter = 1;
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          $title = get_the_title();
          $content = get_the_content();
            echo '<div class="tab blue" <?php post_class(); ?>><input id="inputnumber' . $counter . '" type="checkbox" name="group1" class="trigger"><label for="inputnumber' . $counter . '">' . $title . '</label><span class="content">' . $content . '</span></div>';
          $counter++;
        endwhile;
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- end FAQ-->
```

Comment: You're already within a PHP block.  You don't need the `<?php` that you have within the echo

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm probably being silly but `. post_class() .` prints it outside of the div....

Comment: `post_class()` sounds like it is `echo`ing something for you so you cannot interpolate it into a string like that. You have to finish the `echo`, call `post_class()` on the next line, and restart the `echo` to finish off the string.

Comment: got it to work! I used `echo '<div class="tab blue '. join( ' ', get_post_class() ) .'">` thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, watch your indentation/formatting - future you thanks you! Also, you're mixing up the "echo" functions and the "return" functions, as well as using a php block inside an echo. You'll need to escape the echo or concatenate your string.

If you look at the docs for [`post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) you'll see it *echoes* the value, hence it displaying outside your element. You'll need the [`get_post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class) function. You can also just concatenate your title and content into your echo as well, since you're not reusing them. Note that `get_the_title()` and `the_title()` work similarly to the post class functions in that `get` functions will return it for use/manipulation, and `the` functions will echo it.

```
<!--FAQ-->
<div class="main-faq-div">
    <div class="faq-box">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'faq',
                'posts_per_page' => 40,
                'paged' => 1
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            $counter = 1;
            while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                echo '<div class="tab blue" '. get_post_class() .'>
                    <input id="inputnumber' . $counter . '" type="checkbox" name="group1" class="trigger" />
                    <label for="inputnumber' . $counter . '">'. get_the_title() .'</label><span class="content">'. get_the_content() .'</span>
                </div>';

                $counter++;
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end FAQ-->
```